# Problems Running Cherokee Web Server Admin - config_reader.c:249 - Parsing error

Tags: cherokee

I'm running Cherokee web server 0.99.30 on (Ubuntu Hardy) and I have been having some issues getting the admin to run property.

When I run sudo cherokee-admin -b

```
Login:
  User:              admin
  One-time Password: {password}

Web Interface:
  URL:               http://localhost:9090/

[20/11/2009 22:57:29.733] (error) config_reader.c:249 - Parsing error
Cherokee Web Server 0.99.30 (Nov 20 2009): Listening on port ALL:9090, TLS
disabled, IPv6 disabled, using epoll, 4096 fds system limit, max. 2041
connections, caching I/O, single thread
```

When I go to the admin page I get a 503 Service Unavailable error page.

Any idea about how I could fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have a real answer to this? Python is already installed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not documented but the solution is this simple:

apt-get install python

and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you hit a bug. I'd recommend you to recompile the server adding the `--enable-trace --enable-backtraces` parameters to ./configure and `make CFLAGS="-ggdb -O0"`.

Once you did that, you'd have to execute:

> ```
> CHEROKEE_TRACE=all cherokee-admin -b
> ```

It will print a handful of debug lines then. That's the information the Cherokee web server team would need in order to fix it up. (Additionally, you could send it directly to me, and I'd also take care of it as well.)